# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue. on Amazon Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Hi I tried to deploy my rails application to Amazon Linux.

I got an error

```
 [e93b81e2] Command: cd /var/www/peace/releases/20160511161913 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.1.7" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /var/www/peace/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG [e93b81e2]    An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ec2-user@52.193.101.5: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Please advice Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says to try running `gem install json -v '1.8.3'`. You should SSH into the machine and run this command. This will show you more verbose errors. Sometimes installing gems requires debugging. You might need system dependencies or maybe there is a version conflict error, etc.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working.

Comment: I didn't say it would work. It will show you more verbose (and different) errors. Include the output of running the command on SSH here if you still want help.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried 'gem install json -v '1.8.3'' on Amazon linux with "sudo gem install json -v '1.8.3'" command.
and it successfully installed.

However, when I try to deploy, I got same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue error when i tried to deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180874/an-error-occurred-while-installing-json-1-8-3-and-bundler-cannot-continue-err)